# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have no idea why i got this error when i invoke `createBrowseRecord()` function. My codes as follow, any ideas would be appreciated.

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     fun createBrowseRecord(br:BrowseRecord)

    @Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Composition::class,parentColumns =["id"],childColumns = ["compositionId"] ,onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
    data class BrowseRecord(@PrimaryKey val compositionId:String, val browseTime:Long)

    @Entity
    data class Composition(
            val author: String,
            val commentAmount: Int,
            var cover: String,
            val description: String,
            val downloadURL: String,
            val backGround:String,
            val duration: String,
            @PrimaryKey  val id: String,
            var isLike: Boolean,
            val likeAmount: Int,
            val title: String
    )
```

Comment: can you pleaese show us `createBrowserRecord`? Not the interface, but the `BrowserRecord` object

Comment: @AlanDeep  Thanks,That  you ask ```BrowserRecord``` object has inspired me, I check 
the Database and find the ```Composition``` object wasn't saved into Database.  The question is solved by save ```Composition``` first